# Automatically show text cursor in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

Is it possible to always show text cursor in UISearchBar (not only after touch)?

Comment: Keep in mind, that will always show you the keyboard too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];    
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

Comment: This makes my screen to change like i touched the searchbar, but i do not want all the animation to happen. I just want the cursor to be there always.

Comment: like @iApple said, to have the cursor showing in the searchBar, the keyboard will always show. take the keyboard away, and the cursor goes too..

Answer (score 0):

Also try this...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];    
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];    

}
```